# How can I show the return code of the last run command if it is not zero?

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

How can I show the return code ($?) in my prompt?
This is my current prompt:

```
PROMPT="$[%n@%M\$(~/zshtheme/gitbranch)] %~${NEWLINE}%#> "
```

Which translates to:

```
[luke@telesto (git:master)] /tmp/example
%>
```

How can I show the return code between the `)` and `]` if it is nonzero?

Comment: Questions about configuring your shell as a user are better suited to [unix.se] than Stack Overflow.

Comment: The formatting code `%?` in your `PS1` or `PROMPT`  variable (depending on which one you are using) will be replaced by the exit code of the most recent command.